# #test, #test2 :hover Hover should trigger for both test divs

Tags: css

As the title shows, is it possible to name several elements and apply the same :hover command to them all.

So I don't have to do this:

```
#test:hover > .info, #test2:hover > .info {}
```

Comment: Yes, but that is invalid because you can't have two elements with the same ID.  So only one of those two could ever be possible at one time.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that. I am using classes. I just want an shorter way or applying the same style to multiple elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a class and apply it to those elements.  For example:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .myClass:hover > .info {
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" id="test" class="myClass">Test Link One</a>
    <span id="test2" class="myClass">Test Link Two</span>
</body>
```